# Docker deployment to Heroku crashes with H10 error

Tags: heroku, docker

Sorry if this has an obvious answer, I am a beginner to web deployment. I have a docker image of a simple website that I have made using a Django backend and React frontend. This runs locally with a single docker-compose command, so now I am trying to deploy using the container registry to Heroku. However, I hit a H10 error. I have looked all over StackExchange and referenced several different tutorials including https://dev.to/pacheco/how-to-dockerize-a-node-app-and-deploy-to-heroku-3cch#dev-env-docker-compose, https://medium.com/@justkrup/deploy-a-docker-container-free-on-heroku-5c803d2fdeb1, and https://testdriven.io/blog/deploying-django-to-heroku-with-docker/#heroku-docker-deployment, but I am not sure why this happens.

Currently, I have ensured that $PORT is always an environmental variable that I set in advance and not hard-coded. I know that Heroku does not understand docker-compose files and I would have to translate to a heroku.yaml file, which is why I am choosing to build it locally and then push it instead of building it inside Heroku. I then run the following commands:

```
docker-compose down
docker-compose up --build -d
docker tag colorcode-app registry.heroku.com/gentle-mountain-83925/web
docker push registry.heroku.com/gentle-mountain-83925/web
heroku container:release web
heroku open
```

My Dockerfile and docker-compose.yaml are as follows:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
WORKDIR /ColorCode
COPY . .
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

docker-compose.yaml:

```
version: "3.2"
services:
  colorcode-django:
    restart: always
    container_name: colorcode-django
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: bash -c "python3 manage.py migrate && python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:$PORT"
    ports:
      - "$PORT:$PORT"

  frontend:
    image: colorcode-app
    depends_on:
      - colorcode-django
    restart: always
    command: npm run build
    container_name: frontend
    build:
      context: ./frontend/
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    stdin_open: true
```

If I look at the Heroku logs, I see the following:

```
2021-12-04T22:59:17.190653+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0

2021-12-04T22:59:17.249264+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed

2021-12-04T22:59:17.252452+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting

2021-12-04T22:59:20.485949+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node`

2021-12-04T22:59:21.353094+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0

2021-12-04T22:59:21.445360+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed

2021-12-04T23:23:37.039730+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting

2021-12-04T23:23:41.000659+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node`

2021-12-04T23:23:42.279123+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0

2021-12-04T23:23:42.358744+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed

2021-12-04T23:26:58.691308+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=gentle-mountain-83925.herokuapp.com request_id=031eb117-db13-4162-af63-664bc3c083cf fwd="204.38.40.66" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Since it runs locally without a problem, why does it crash with an H10 error on Heroku?
Thanks in advance!